# for loop exists premature in selenium - DOM objects changed on Run Time

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to iterate over html elements in a webpage to remove them. For an instance have too many items in a shopping cart (this is not shopping cart though).

number of items is >50.

But the following for loop exits after clicking the first item, any thought what am I missing?

```
for i in  range(0, len(x)):
        time.sleep(2)
        if x[i].is_displayed():
            print(i)


            pageClicked = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
                ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                                             "/html/body/div/div/div/div/router-view/div[1]/div/div[1]")))

            pageClicked.click()

            x[i].click() #removes the item

            """This is hardcoded part, TODO remove this """
            removalConfirm = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
                ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/ux-dialog-container/div/div/ux-dialog/ux-dialog-body/form/div[2]/button[1]")))
            #
            """"remove from the wishlist """
            removalConfirm.click() #receive confirmation
            i=i+1
```

Comment: This information is not enough, share the more info like what is `x` in your code and what is its length? It would be better if you provide some site link for easy debugging...

Comment: not actually. Please see my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

On the fly the DOM objects changed, so I had to recapture the DOM objects. Following work.

```
 x = driver.find_elements_by_id(
                ObjectManager().getObjectIdentifierValue(driver, "Patron", "WishlistPage", "wishListCloseAll"))

            #print(len(x))

            for i in  range(0, len(x)-1):
                time.sleep(2)
                """Since the dom objects change on the fly, they need to named"""
                x = driver.find_elements_by_id(
                    ObjectManager().getObjectIdentifierValue(driver, "Patron", "WishlistPage", "wishListCloseAll"))

                #print('lenght of x', len(x))


                if  x[i].is_displayed():
                    if x[i].is_displayed():
                        x[i].click()
                       #print('x', x[i])

                        """This is hardcoded part, TODO remove this """
                        removalConfirm = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
                            ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/ux-dialog-container/div/div/ux-dialog/ux-dialog-body/form/div[2]/button[1]")))
                        #
                        """"remove from the wishlist """
                        removalConfirm.click()
                        i=i
                        #print(i)

                time.sleep(2)
```